# Tides on an Inhabitable planet with rings

Tags: planets, planetary-rings

I've occasionally pondered the notion of an inhabited planet similar to Earth in terms of size, gravity, atmosphere etc., but with rings circling around it an a similar manner to Saturn. One question- how would the ocean tides be affected?

Comment: @king of panes   Calling the particles in Saturn's rings  and in the rings of your hypothetical planet "asteroids" is likely to annoy people.  They should be called ring particles..  And there is no theory that the particles in the rings of Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, & Neptune are particles that were attracted and captured.

Comment: Look at this video from Artifexian, he covered this topic quite well. [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CItDiuBWP5I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CItDiuBWP5I)

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, @Bedlasky.  Link-only answers are discouraged, because link rot can claim them.  If there's a relevant bit of the video, transcribe it as part of your answer.

Comment: Elsewhere on this site are answers to "can Earth (or an Earth-like planet) have rings", and the answer is generally "briefly", since they'd have to be _particularly close_ to Earth, to be within its Roche limit and not accumulate into larger satellites.

Answer (score 5):

Not in any amount that you could reasonably measure.

## Earth Can't Hold Onto Massive Rings

This is true of any planet with rings.  Saturn's spectacular rings are 0.00001% of its mass.  By comparison, the greatest contributor to our tides, the moon, is 1.2% of Earth's mass.

So if Earth had rings proportional to its mass, they'd a) barely be visible, both because they'd have to be *within geostationary orbit*, and b) their mass would have pretty much no effect on the tides, even assuming it was all gathered in one place, because...

#### Rings, By Definition, Pull Both Ways

Even notwithstanding the tiny mass of an Earth-like planet's rings, they'd be *evenly* distributed around the Earth.  The tides occur because of the shifting position (relative to the surface of the Earth) of the Moon.

So, assuming an Earth-like planet had rings, they'd either be temporary (in that they would be outside of the Roche limit and particles would start clumping up) or very, very small.  **In either case, they would not be massive.  But even if they were, the even distribution of their mass would mean that they would have no perceptible effect on the planet's tides.**